# MessageMedia Webhooks PHP SDK Error

Tags: php, sdk, messagemedia

I was trying to run the MessageMedia Webhooks PHP SDK and then this happened. Can anyone help me out?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CreateWebhookRequest' not found
>   in /Users/james/mm/webhooks_sdks/php-sdk/test-webhooks/create.php:12
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 {main}
>         thrown in /Users/isthi/mm/webhooks_sdks/php-sdk/test-webhooks/create.php on line
>   12

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the code please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the SDK via composer?

Run the Composer command to install the latest stable version of the Messages SDK:

`composer require messagemedia/messages-sdk`